# Is S3 file tagging helps for filter through the created tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there way in S3 file tagging helps for filter through the created tags and does it helps us to filter the results based on certain tags.
Is there anyway for bucket tagging???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 file tagging doesn't help for filtering and it is cost effective(S3 Object Tagging   $0.01 per 10,000 tags per month).